# How does the scale factor and further the Hubble constant depend on the inflation potential?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

I've found standard derivations showing how one can integrate the Friedmann equation to obtain $a(t)$ given $P_{tot}$ and $\rho_{tot}$. I'd like to know how $a(t)$ depends on the inflation potential.

Comment: It will depend on the model you have in mind, the one I am somewhat familiar with is slow roll inflation, but I don't know enough to answer the question. I just know that the equations can be written in terms of the dynamics of the field and it's potential.

Answer (score 1):

The Friedmann equation, $$H^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2 + V(\phi)\right)$$ relates the Hubble parameter to the inflaton energy density.  During slow roll, $\dot{\phi}^2 \ll V$, with $H = \dot{a}/{a}$, $$\frac{{\rm d}a}{a} \propto \sqrt{V(\phi)}{\rm d}t.$$  Now, $V$ in the above is a function of $\phi$, and the integral is over time, $t$.  We therefore need $\phi(t)$, which we can get via the Klein-Gordon equation, $$3H\dot{\phi} = -V'(\phi).$$

Note that it's in general not possible to get an analytic expression for $a(t)$ for an arbitrary inflaton potential, and instead you'll need to solve the coupled Friedmann and Klein-Gordon equations to obtain $a(t)$ parametrically.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Do I need to do it parametrically even for a simple potential for a massive inflaton field, say, V(\phi) = 1/2 m^2 \phi^2, if I don't want to assume slow roll so I can't neglect the derivatives of the potential?

Comment: If you're not assuming slow roll, you've got to solve the coupled differential equations: 1) $\ddot{\phi} + 3H\dot{\phi} + m^2\phi$ and 2) $H^2 = (8\pi G/3)(\dot{\phi}^2/2 + m^2\phi^2/2)$, with $H = \dot{a}/a$.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Wouldn't there be a $-k/a^2$ term in the second equation? 2) Does this have an analytic solution?

Comment: 1) Why would there be?  Presumably that would come from a gradient term, but the field is spatially homogeneous: perhaps you're thinking of the perturbation equation?  2) I have not idea ;)...haven't tried to solve it!

Comment: 1) Isn't there a curvature term in the Friedmann equation (see for example [here in eq. 4.21](http://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/~dullemond/lectures/cosmology_2011/Chapter_4.pdf))?

Comment: Oh, yes, generally there is a curvature term. But, since inflation rapidly drives the universe to flatness, this term is omitted in the standard scenarios.